# How to remove an id out of a path using a Java Regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get rid of an "id" in URI paths and I can only use Java regex transformation.

The paths look like this:

```
/web/service/1223345/add
/web/service/1223345/delete
/web/service/v2/1223345/add
/web/service/1223345
/web/service/do
```

The id is always a series of numbers. In the example above it is "1223345".

I have tried a couple of regexes but none of them worked. Here are my tries:

```
(/\w.*)/?[0-9]*/(.*)
([^0-9]+){0,}
(/.*/)[0-9]*(/.*)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String input = "/web/service/1223345/add";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("/\\d*/","/"));
```

Output:

```
/web/service/add
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are after removing id, you could do the following:

```
String input = "/web/service/v2/1223345/add";
String removed = input.replaceAll("/\\d*/?", "/");
System.out.println(removed);
```

Note that arnoud's regex "/\d*/" will not work for e.g. /web/service/1223345.
Question mark at the end of the regex takes care of such cases: "/\d*/?"

If on the other hand you are after extracting id:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?/(\\d*?)(/.*)?$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String id = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(id);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to remove it put the tool uses the Pattern class like you use it to extract the id. Unfortunately I cannot change the implementation just the regex.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Tool uses Pattern class to remove id?
Could you paste your code snippet here, it might be clearer from it.